# vscode require not finding soap module

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, visual-studio-code

I'm pretty new to visual studio code, and I'm having a little trouble with `require` method.

here's my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var soap = require('soap');
```

that's not working, it gives me "module not found" error.
obviously I've installed soap module without any error with `npm install soap` command.
if i try the same code with node cli it works.

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you use the `--save` option when installing the module? i.e. `npm install soap --save`?

Comment: i didn't, now i tried but it doesn't work. what should --save do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had installed the npm package in a folder that vs code wasn't looking in.
solved reinstalling the package in